# Vuejs Component stop open http connection

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a **vuejs** component that streams an `MP4` stream over `http` but once the component is destroyed the http connection stays open and keeps downloading content until i refresh the browser.

When the component is mounted i set a `<video>` tags `src` equal to the MP4 url, which in turn automatically opens the http connection to the MP4 and it starts downloading and displaying video, which is expected and desired. BUT when the component is destroyed in the `destroyed()` hook, the connection stays open and keeps downloading video.

I have tried to use `XMLHttpRequest()` to create the connection but thats not working either. Is there a way to essentially kill the http connection upon destroying the vue component?

**vue component**:

```
<template>
    <video muted :src="mp4Src"></video>
</template>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
        mp4Src: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      this.mp4Src = 'http://my-stream.com/123.mp4';
  },
  destroyed() {
    // Setting this to this.mp4Src = ''; doesnt work
    console.log('How to destroying stream?');
  }
}
```

Comment: Any code examples?

Comment: @AndrewShmig Editied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in my case i was actually able to resolve this in the `beforeDestroy()` hook after finding out that my component wasnt being destroyed. The reason it wasnt being destroyed was because the components were dynamically created in a `v-if` loop and the `:key` binding wasnt a completely unique key, so this caused the components to not be updated/destroyed correctly. Once i corrected this `:key` binding it started to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `ref` property to the `video` element:

```
<video ref="video" muted :src="mp4Src"></video>
```

Then, on `destroyed` hook get the [`MediaStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MediaStream) and stop it:

```
this
  .$refs
  .video
  .srcObject
  .getTracks()
  .forEach(track => track.stop());
this.$refs.video.srcObject = null;
```

Comment: `.srcObject` is null in both `destroyed()` and `beforeDestroy()` hooks.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeDestroy), you should be using beforeDestroy

> At this stage the instance is still fully functional

Instead of Destroyed [api](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#destroyed):

> Vue instance have been unbound

Edit:

Seems like `vue` has trouble closing that connection in the `video element`. But I think the problem might be with the `video element` self. I read around I found that people had issues in the past to properly unload a video element.

I have created a work around, seems to close connections. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oJRajy)

```
beforeDestroy() {
   this.$refs["mp4"].load();
 }
```

Comment: @JeremyWalters, it's not the Vue problem, it's the browser problem. Have searched answers for similar questions - the only working solution is to completely remove HTML-element and than re-create it.

Comment: @AndrewShmig Thanks for confirming. Suspected that. Have you looked at my Codepen, that seems to work? You welcome to edit your finding in the answer.

Comment: @JeremyWalters, yes, I have seen your codepen and had another question: how do we measure and check if the browser is still loading the video or not in background? Your solutions seems fine.

Comment: Open devtools: Disabled Cache. Open Network Tab. Select `Media` Filter. When you play the video you would see it downloading. When you press the stop button it would stop downloading. Destroying it normally without ` this.$refs["mp4"].load();`, you will it still downloads.